# Нет коллекций Map, Set и тд

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

Проект на VS15, классы typescript лежат каждый в отдельном файле. В свойствах проекта на вкладке "Сборка typescript" указано: Версия ECMAScript - ECMAScript5,
Система модулей - CommonJs, так же указан файл куда объединяется вывод javascript.
Всё работает, но нет доступа к коллекциям Map,Set и т.д. Ткните носом, уважаемые, что нужно еще сделать, что бы получить к ним доступ. Спасибо.

Comment: а tsconfig.json есть?

Answer (score 1):

Поставил новый плагин для typescript, указал систему модулей - ES 2015 и всё появилось.